# IIS 6.0 - grant domain users access to Websites/App Pools

Tags: iis, iis-6

For some odd reason, I cannot allow domain users to access IIS once connected to an RDP server.

I've been trying all the authentication types from the Authentication and Access Control properties in IIS but without success.

Active Directory OS - Windows Server 2008 Standard x64
RDP server where IIS is hosted - Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition

Are Group Policies required by any chance?  Just as a heads up, websites can only be accessed when assigning a domain user the Domain Admin privileges but it's not feasible at this point.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

The user doesn't need to be a domain administrator, just a member of the local administrator group on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

I'm assuming you want to allow users to manage IIS with something like **inetmgr.exe**. According to Microsoft's documentation the user must be a local administrator to run the inetmgr program and make changes to IIS.

There is, however, a hack to allow non-admins access to the IIS metabase. Unfortunately, I don't remember what it is off the top of my head and I don't know if it actually allows non-admins to run **inetmgr**. I can check with one of my coworkers if you need me to.

Comment: I managed thanks for your feedback guys..  i just had to include the users in the local administrator group.